# How do I return the items in a list created in pyqt4 to alphabetical order

Tags: python, pyqt4

Here is the code that I have written but it does not work:

```
def orderitems(self):
        self.ui.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)
```

Comment: I think you should enable sorting before you add the items

Comment: provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar to pyqt but sorting elements is done by `sorted(list)`